# Why there is no shell?

Tags: command-line

I downloaded the ubuntu operating system (Ubuntu 12.04.3) because i learn computer science , and for that i need the shell but on ubuntu there is no shell.
Do anybody know why is that? or where i can find the shell window?

Answer (score 3):

The shortcut to the terminal is  <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Or the long way: open dash by pressing the super key and start typing terminal.

[image]

That option opens gnome-terminal and the shell it shows is bash:

[image]

You can lock the launcher to the left side for easier access.